# Differential Equations Textbook with Emphasis on Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I don't really like the textbook I've got for my differential equations class (Differential Equations with Applications by George Simmons) so I'm looking for a secondary source to use.

At the beginning of the semester our professor said that there's a lot of linear algebra used in differential equations but though I've seen hints at it, I haven't seen any bit of linear algebra explicitly stated.  I did pretty well in linear algebra.  Is there a textbook that covers differential equations from the standpoint of building on linear algebra ideas?  That is I'm looking for a textbook that explicitly points out linear algebra and motivates its theorems and such as much as possible from linear algebra ideas.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Comment: what is the textbook you got?

Comment: One textbook that I find easy and friendly to read is *Differential equations, Dynamical Systems and an Introduction to Chaos* by Hirsch, Smale and Devaney. It starts very slowly and covers a lot of interesting examples with pictures. There is a specific chapter devoted to linear algebra, so you might find it useful.

Comment: @Qidi Oh wow -- the first edition looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  And it's only $4 on Amazon right now.  I'll definitely be getting a copy.  Thanks.